# Cannot reenter draw mode after inserting 3D object

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm new to Blender and I may be doing something wrong.
My goal is to use two images on textured planes for reference and draw over them.

1. Create new scene (File -> New 2D Animation)
2. Draw something (everything is working)
3. Add new workspace (General -> Layout)
4. Add Mesh -> Plane
5. Go back to 2D Full Canvas / 2D Animation workspace

Now I cannot select the 2D drawing, cannot get out of object mode, cannot draw anything else. Grease pencil doesn't work anymore and nothing related to what is drawn is selectable/editable.

I have Blender 2.80 Beta

Thank you.

Mihai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

In order to be able to select Draw mode, you have to select a "Stroke" element.

My problem was that after creating a 3D object (a reference image plane, in my case), the object became selected and it was drawn over the little cube-cross gizmo by which one can select back the Stroke (they were both in the center of the screen).
I then tried selecting the stroke by clicking on the drawn lines, but clicking on the drawing does not select the stroke!

Thus, your options are:

- enter wireframe mode and select "show all scene transparent", from the top right corner and select the cube-cross gizmo that selects the stroke
- move the newly created object out of the way in order to see the gizmo and select the stroke
- select the stroke from the "Scene Collections" tab, from the right of the screen. Scene collections are not visible in the "2D Full Canvas" workspace, so you have to switch to one that has it (ex: 2D Animation, Layout, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

This will return the workflow of the Grease Pencil in Blender (2.83.5) from the Layout workspace.
[image: Layout Workspace]

I will start by returning to **2D Full Canvas** from the newly created **Layout** workspace created in OP Step 3.
[image: Open 2D (Full) Canvas Workspace]

With no Grease Pencil objects in the world, the Draw Mode doesn't exist returning to **2D (Full) Canvas**.
(continued steps)
5. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > Grease Pencil > Blank
[image: Create Grease Pencil]

6. Drag out another Viewport and switch it to Outliner.
   [image: Switch 3D Viewport to Outliner]
7. Select the GPencil layer in Outliner then, drag in another Editor and switch to Properties.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, had the same problem.
When you are in the 2d animation tab, in the middle of the screen there is a square with a cross. Click on it and you can choose 'Draw' again.

Comment: Thank you :) This is the solution in a general situation, but I had also another problem. I posted a solution describing the entire problem and how to resolve.